# Storing and Accessing Dictionary values in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool> sampleDict= new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool>();
```

which I added in Session

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("SessionsampleDict", sampleDict);
}
```

NOw I need to add values into Dictionary, so my code goes like.

```
sampleDict.Add(DictKey, true);
```

NOw issue is when I am coming back to my page using postback, I am loosing all my data in `sampleDict`.

What I am doing wrong here ? How to add values of dictionary on session ?

Comment: How are you reading from the session? Are you in MVC or Web forms?

Comment: @Wheels73 Its Webforms

Comment: post little more code where sampleDict is being referred. One possibility is you are re instantiating the dictionary and not taking it from session.

Comment: @Vijayakrishna How can I take it from session and add values ?

Comment: On postback you should do sampleDict=(Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool>)HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionsampleDict"]

Comment: All the answers that say `sampleDict` is not stored in the session are wrong. The session will store its reference, so if it is updated, you should be able to access it through the session. You are doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sampleDict` will not be in session, only its values are copied to session. You need to reassign the value to session variable after modifying them. or else you can try like this:

```
((Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool>)HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionsampleDict"]).Add(DictKey, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool> _sessionDict;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack || !(Session["SessionsampleDict"] is Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool>))
    {
        Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool> localDict = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool>();
        Session["SessionsampleDict"] = localDict;
    }
    _sessionDict = (Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool>)Session["SessionsampleDict"];
}
```

Now you can access the Dictionary using the local ref `_sessionDict` elsewhere in your page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that when you add the sampleDict to your session you are making a copy of it and storing it, so when you call

```
sampleDict.Add(...)
```

It is not updating the one in your session.

You may have to either update the one in your session every time you update the other one, or find a way to manipulate only the one in your session.

```
sampleDict.Add(...);
HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionsampleDict"] = sampleDict;
```

Something like that?

Not too familiar with the Session class but I've made a rough guess. Let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

When you save dictionary in session and then you modify dictionary,  session object will not be updated, since it is no more the same object. Session can be stored in database, redis or in another storage, so it is only clone to original object.